# Linq get object or new object from Dictionary <object,bool>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, linq-to-objects, default-value

I know there has been a few posts from me today, but lets hope you guys continue to be awesome...

so I have a

```
Dictionary<obj, bool> objDict;
```

I am trying to get a single object if it exists if not return a new version of it...

```
obj foo = objDict.Keys.SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == t.id).DefaultIfEmpty((new obj() );
```

this throws a few errors mostly around conversions...

Is there a way to return a single key from a dictionary or a default of a new key in the event it doesn't exist...

Comment: No, there is no such thing. The dictionary won't automatically create a new object for you. Use `TryGetValue()` and if it returns `false`, create `new obj()` yourself.

Answer (score 4):

`TryGetValue` tries to get a value from a key, if there is in fact a value for that key.

If you want to add a new value to the dictionary when the key doesn't exist, then there is no *single* method that will do all of that for you (`ConcurrentDictionary` has one though, named `GetOrAdd`).  To get that behavior for a `Dictionary` you'll need to create your own method that calls `TryGetValue` and adds a new key/value pair whenever it returns `false`.

Note that you should not be doing a linear search of a `Dictionary` to try to find the key equal to a key that you have.  The whole *design* of the `Dictionary` is to allow fast lookups, which you're not even using.

Comment: correct, I know I am not using it as designed here, this is part of a conversion as there is no direct conversion between the key/obj type, once the dict is updated/completed it will be used elsewhere as it is inteded.

Comment: @asuppa You already have a `Dictionary`, and you're trying to get the value for a key.  Given that situation, you should be using either the indexer or `TryGetValue`, not iterating through `Keys`.  If you don't actually have a `Dictionary` yet then that's not reflected in the question.

Comment: actually I am trying to get the obj (key) to update a property within the key, or create a new obj (key) and add it if required...

Comment: @asuppa And given that situation `TryGetValue` is *exactly* the right tool for the job.  Iterating `Keys` is not.  Try to get the value from the dictionary, if you can, update the value, if not, add a new key/value pair.  It's exactly the behavior that you want, and it leverages the dictionary's ability to perform lookups much quicker than iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
obj yourObject;
objDict.TryGetValue(t.Id, out yourObject) ? yourObject : new obj();
```